# Temp file not being deleted

Tags: bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm trying to create a temporary file in my pipeline, then use that file in another rule.

For example, I have two rules in a .smk file:

```
#Unzip adapter trimmed fastq file
rule unzip_fastq:
  input:
    '{sample}.adapterTrim.round2.fastq.gz',
  output:
    temp('{sample}.adapterTrim.round2.fastq')
  conda:
    '../envs/rep_element.yaml'
  shell:
    'gunzip -c {input[0]} > {output[0]}'


#Run bowtie2 to align to rep elements and parse output
rule parse_bowtie2_output_realtime:
  input:
    '{sample}.adapterTrim.round2.fastq'
  output:
    'rep_element_pipeline/{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam'
  params:
    bt2=config["ref"]["bt2_index_path"], eid=config["ref"]["enst2id"]
  conda:
    '../envs/rep_element.yaml'
  shell:
    'perl ../scripts/parse_bowtie2_output_realtime_includemultifamily.pl '
    '{input[0]} {params.bt2} {output[0]} {params.eid}'
```

`{sample}.adapterTrim.round2.fastq` is used once and should ultimately be deleted upon completion. However, I'm finding that this file is uploaded to Amazon S3, even with the addition of `temp()`. I'm also finding that this file is removed locally, but still persists on S3.

Am I doing this correctly? `'{sample}.adapterTrim.round2.fastq'` is not currently written in the rule-all of the Snakefile.

We ultimately need to prevent this file from being uploaded to S3, so if there is a way to specify not to upload this file in the rule, that would be useful.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am reading the code correctly, but where in the code there is an upload to s3? (it should not happen by default, IIUC)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the snippet in the question is not consistent with actual use, since for S3 files one would need to wrap file names in `remote`.

However, as a general solution, [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html) contains the following:

> The remote() wrapper is mutually-exclusive with the temp() and protected() wrappers.

Hence, if you intend to use a `temp` file, make sure it's not wrapped in `remote`, or explicitly wrap the file in `local`.

Comment: Also, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70712745/10693596.