# Snakemake temp()

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have Snakemake hooked up to an S3 account, and I'm wanting to delete certain temp() files after processing our pipeline.

I have a rule that designates certain files as temp(). Below is an example of one:

```
 #Split rep element mapped bam file into subfiles
rule split_rep_bam:
  input:
    'rep_element_pipeline/{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam'
  output:
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/AA.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/AC.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/AG.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/AN.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/AT.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/CA.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/CC.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/CG.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/CN.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/CT.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/GA.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/GC.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/GG.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/GN.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/GT.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/NA.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/NC.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/NG.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/NN.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/NT.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/TA.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/TC.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/TG.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/TN.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp'),
    temp('rep_element_pipeline/TT.{sample}.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_' + config["ref"]["bt2_index"] + '.sam.tmp')
  conda:
    '../envs/rep_element.yaml'
  params:
    fp=full_path
  shell:
    'perl ../scripts/split_bam_to_subfiles.pl {input[0]} '
    '{params.fp}/rep_element_pipeline/'
```

I've been running Snakemake as such:

```
snakemake --default-remote-provider S3 --default-remote-prefix '$s3' --use-conda --cores 32 --rerun-incomplete --printshellcmds --delete-temp-output
```

Where I've specified the `--delete-temp-output` option.

When running this rule, it appears snakemake is deleting these files. However, these files still persist in S3. Does anyone know why these files aren't being deleted in S3?

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Deleting 20211222-rp030/rep_element_pipeline/AA.APP-01_rep_1_Ribo_R1.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_bt2_hg38.sam.tmp
Deleting 20211222-rp030/rep_element_pipeline/AC.APP-01_rep_1_Ribo_R1.fastq.gz.mapped_vs_bt2_hg38.sam.tmp
```

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/9505705/

Comment: Just a guess -- could it be because you don't have any of the output files mentioned in the `shell` portion of the rule? Something like `touch {output}` as the third command after running the `{params.fp}/rep_element_pipeline/` may do it?

Answer (score 3):

This question is very similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70683642/10693596), and the core issue is that:

> the remote() wrapper is mutually-exclusive with the temp() and protected() wrappers.

Source: [docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/remote_files.html).

One solution is to explicitly mark files using `local` function, so it would look like this:

```py
rule some_rule:
     output: temp(local('test.txt'))
     run: # ...
```